# How to execute PHP code after automaticly creating it using string concatenation?

Tags: php

I have a function that will create a php code that will do a bitwire operation.

this code is generated by function

```
1 | 2 | 4
```

what I want to do is return the result of the operation. `return (1 | 2 | 4);`
I tried to use `eval()` but I get the following error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ..... : eval()'d code on line 1
```

The flowing is my code

```
<?php

class Roles
{

    protected $rolesList = array();

    public function __construct(){

        $this->rolesList = array(
                                'can_use' => 1,
                                'can_view' => 2,      //0000000001
                                'can_update' => 4,    //0000000010
                                'can_insert' => 8,    //0000000100
                                'can_delete' => 16     //0000001000
                            );

    }

    public function mapRoles(){

        if ( func_num_args() == 0 ){
            return false; //no args passed
        }

        $tmp = array();
        $parmeters = func_get_args();

        foreach($parmeters as $arg){
            $tmp[] = $this->rolesList[$arg];
        }

        $cmd = implode(' | ', $tmp);
        return eval($cmd);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: "I have a function that will create a php code that will do a bitwire operation." --- this is where your implementation started being wrong.

Comment: What if you just take `$tmp` and apply `|` operator to its members?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Well, you iterate over its members and appy it? Or if you like oneliners then `array_reduce($data, function($a, $b) { return $a | $b; }, 0);`

Comment: like this you mean, right?   `foreach($parmeters as $arg){
   $val |= $this->rolesList[$arg];
  }`

Comment: That's right. Or using a fancy `array_reduce`

Comment: aha, you got it :) please post your comments an an answer and I will give you the answer :) thank you so much

Comment: If you need `eval`, append `return` and `;` to string. Like `eval('return (1 | 2 | 4);')`;

Comment: Consider the following - File 1: `return "Apple";` File 2: `echo include __DIR__.'/file-1.php';` Output: `Apple`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> function that will create a php code that will do a bitwire operation

Usually one does not generate php code in their code.

Instead you might just iterate over array elements and mutually `|` it:

```
$val = 0;
foreach($parmeters as $arg) {
    $val |= $this->rolesList[$arg];
}
```

the other one line implementation that uses an `array_reduce` might look like this:

```
$val = array_reduce($data, function($a, $b) { return $a | $b; }, 0);
```